# An ARC compatible charting framework for iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, charts, automatic-ref-counting

I'm looking for an ARC compatible charting framework for iOS. I'm aware of the existence of Core Plot, but apparently this framework is MRC and does not work in an ARC environment. Googling didn't turn up anything decent.

Specifically I'm looking to draw a histogram (bar chart) with two axes and and some basic display of the values on an iPhone, so nothing too complicated actually.

Does anyone know of an ARC alternative to Core Plot that can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use Core Plot in your project even though it's manual reference counting.

In your Target -> Buld Phases -> Compile Sources you can add a compiler flag to disable ARC on Core Plot related files.

1. Navigate to Target -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources
2. Select your desired files
3. Add the compiler flag **-fno-objc-arc**

Core Plot should now work in your ARC enabled project.

Answer (score 2):

There is the slightly less sophisticated [ECGraph](http://code.google.com/p/ecgraph/), but I would really suggest you use Core Plot and simply disable ARC for those files, or link the project as a reference. ARC binaries are compatible with non-ARC binaries.

Comment: So if I would just use the Core Plot binary I don't need to worry about ARC? Probably I'd have to turn of ARC for the header files?

Comment: You don't need to - just forget about it. ARC has nothing to do with header files.

Comment: In your .h files you can declare properties using `@property (strong)` in an ARC project, in a MRC project you can't use that, you need to use `retain`. So it has some impact on header files I'd say.

Comment: property declarations simply direct the compiler on what to do. If the compiler has already done the work (as in the case of a static binary), they have no meaning. Also, I would suggest you read up on strong vs retain. Your ARC enabled project will work with both.

Comment: Yes I know that, but for Core Plot you need to copy a folder with uncompiled header files to your project, even if you're using the binary, for some reason. I have had issues with declaring properties in a way that wasn't supported in an ARC project, possibly it wasn't because of using retain, I don't remember exactly. But having ARC enabled does have some impact on uncompiled header files surely?

Answer (score 1):

You can turn ARC off for CorePlot by setting this `-fno-objc-arc` flag to it's source files by selecting your project file in XCode, selecting your target, going to 'Build Phases'->'Compile Sources'.